# Try Catch Exception Program

Tags: c#

Hello I am facing a problem in my C# Program. The Question is:

> "Write a method `ReadNumber(int start, int end)` that reads an integer from the console in the range `[start...end]`. In case the input integer is not valid or it is not in the required range throw the appropriate exception.

Using this method, write a program that takes `10` integers `a1, a2, ..., a10` such that `1 < a1 < ... < a10 < 100`."

The Code I have so far:

```
public class NumberRange
{
    public void ReadNumber(int start, int end)
    {
        try
        {
            int [] arr = new int [10];
            int j = 1;

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++, j++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Integer No " + j + ":- ");
                arr[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Array Values Are:- ");

            for(int k = 0;k < 10; k++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[k]);

                if (start < arr[k] && arr[k] < end)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("These Values Are In The Range!");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                "These Values Are Not Valid Or In The Range Between 1-100!");
        }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NumberRange range = new NumberRange();
        range.ReadNumber(1,100);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

When I run this program, it doesn't catch the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception.

*I tried so many times but the program doesn't give the right output that I am expecting.*

Comment: What output *does* it give you? According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Int32_Parse_System_String_), `Int32.Parse(string)` will throw a `FormatException` if the input string is not a valid number. But you're not catching that exception anywhere. And then when you're looping through the numbers to see if they're in the valid range, I don't see anywhere that you throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if it fails - you only write to the console if a value is valid.

Comment: You might look into the `int.TryParse` method, which returns `true` if the input string can be converted, and which sets an `out` parameter to the converted value.

Comment: Also, my take on the assignement is that the method is supposed to return a *single* integer within the range. Then you need to call the method 10 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you catching an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`? If we look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Int32_Parse_System_String_), we see that it throws a `FormatException` if the input is not a valid number.

Also note that there are two conditions where we throw exceptions:

1. The input is not a valid integer
2. The integer is not within the specified range

So we can catch that `FormatException` and then throw our own exception with a custom message. And then we just need to check that the converted value is within the specified range, and if it's not, then we throw a different exception with a custom message:

```
public static int ReadNumber(int start, int end)
{
    // Make sure they entered a valid range, otherwise our comparison logic will fail later
    if (end < start) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("'end' cannot be less than 'start'");
    }

    // Get user input and create a variable to store the converted value
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    int result;

    // Try to parse the input into our result
    try
    {
        result = int.Parse(input);
    }
    catch(FormatException)
    {
        // If we get here, it means the input was not a valid number
        throw new ArgumentException($"{input} is not a valid integer.");
    }

    // Last thing to do is make sure the number is within range
    if (result < start)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Input cannot be less than {start}.");
    }
    else if (result > end)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Input cannot be greater than {end}.");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you need to throw the exception when appropriate:

```
if (start < arr[k] && arr[k] < end)
{
    Console.WriteLine("These Values Are In The Range!");
}
else
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("These Values Are Not Valid Or In The Range Between 1-100!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Catching one Exception and then throwing a similar exception seems coutner intuitive, and only makes the code hard to read.

It is true that the quickest way to test for int is to try to parse, but you do not want to deal with all those messy exceptions it throw. Why not use TryParse()?

```
string input; //set outside of this codes scope

bool isInteger;
int output;

isInteger = Int.TryPrase(input, out output);

if(isInteger){
  //Do stuff with the integer
  //Like range checks, adding to collection, etc.
}
else{
  //Throw an exception
}
```

There, no try/case inside `ReadNumber` that needs to be written. All the Try/case is inside `TryParse` or outside `ReadNumber`.

It is possible they did not want to you to use this way to test int (instead writing basic check code yourself). But in that case, this code is easily adapted.

**Footnotes**

If you are interested in how to deal with the Parse exceptions properly, I did once wrote a basic TryParse() immitation:

```
//Parse throws ArgumentNull, Format and Overflow Exceptions.
//And they only have Exception as base class in common, but identical handling code (output = 0 and return false).

bool TryParse(string input, out int output){
  try{
    output = int.Parse(input);
  }
  catch (Exception ex){
    if(ex is ArgumentNullException ||
      ex is FormatException ||
      ex is OverflowException){
      //these are the exceptions I am looking for. I will do my thing.
      output = 0;
      return false;
    }
    else{
      //Not the exceptions I expect. Best to just let them go on their way.
      throw;
    }
  }

  //I am pretty sure the Exception replaces the return value in exception case. 
  //So this one will only be returned without any Exceptions, expected or unexpected
  return true;
}
```